# Is the solution to $AB + BA^T = C$ unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C$ be a nonzero symmetric matrix, and suppose $A$ is invertible. Is there a unique symmetric matrix $B$ such that
$$AB + BA^T = C$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is antisymmetric such that $A^T=-A$, and suppose that $B$ is a solution. Then define:
$$B=E+a\mathbb{I}$$ and then:
$$\begin{aligned}
AE+EA^T+aA+aA^T&=C\\
AE+EA^T+aA-aA&=C\\
AE+EA^T&=C\\
\end{aligned}
$$
hence $E$ is a solution and thus $B$ is not unique when $A$ is antisymmetric.

More generally, suppose that $B$ is a solution. Then define:
$$B=E+F$$ and suppose that $F$ exists such that:
$$AF+FA^T=0$$
and then:
$$\begin{aligned}
AE+EA^T+AF+FA^T&=C\\
AE+EA^T&=C\\
\end{aligned}
$$
hence $E$ is again a solution and thus $B$ is not unique.

Comment: The question then is what conditions are required for $F$ to exist...